# How do I plot a function in python that looks like the one in the picture?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, legend-properties

I need to plot this graph (exactly as in the picture). It is sin and cos of x, where x are equally spaced 100 numbers between 0 and 2 pi.
[image]

So far, I wrote

```
x=np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi,100)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5)) 
plt.yticks(np.arange(-1,1.25,0.25))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 7, 1))
plt.plot(x,np.cos(x),'r',label="sine")
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),'b',label="cosine")
plt.xlabel('x (in radians)')
plt.legend(loc=3)
```

But the plot I get looks like this
[image]

How do I make the legend smaller, the box for the legend in grey and the plot indented?

Editing: I am using the version of Matplotlib 2.1.0 [proof][https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFXFV.png]

Comment: If you run your code from the command-line (instead of through Jupyter notebook) do you get the same result?

Comment: You could have more than one matplotlib version installed on your system. What does `print(plt.matplotlib.__version__)` show you?

Comment: yes, the same ones

Comment: it shows 2.1.0.

Comment: So the real question is why matplotlib <1.5 is used, even though matplotlib 2.1 is installed?! (The picture itself is no proof of anything). In that case edit the question with the relevant information.

Comment: What happens if you add `plt.matplotlib.style.use('default')` at the top of your script? (I can reproduce your problem **if** I add `plt.matplotlib.style.use('classic')` to your code, using matplotlib version 2.0.2...)

Answer (score 0):

The first plot shown here is produced with a matplotlib version >2.0, while the second plot is produced with an earlier version of matplotlib.

Hence the easiest option to obtain the first plot is to use the newest matplotlib version (currently 2.1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I only downloaded python on Monday with all the functions from it. So I guess I am using the newest version of matplotlib

Comment: If the second shown plot is what you get when you run the code, you **are not** using the newest matplotlib version.

Comment: @huda95x: Change `plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 6, 1))` to `plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 7, 1))` to show the `6` ticker label.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit now the question with the correction. But it still  does not look the same as needed. But better though